# C++ Multi-threading giving a templated std::bind to another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I try to give a `std::bind` to another existing thread currently waiting in a `condition_variable`. I really want to keep this other thread alive and not creating another one.
But I don't know how to give this `std::bind` to the other thread, due to the fact that everything is decided at compile-time.

I know that boost thread pool manage that, and I really wonder how and I'd like doing it without boost.

Here is some pseudo-code

```
class Exec
{
  template<typename Func, typename... Args>
  auto call(Func func, Args... args)
  {
    sendWork(std::bind(func, this->someMemberClass, args...)); // Async         
    return getResults(); // Waiting til get results                             
  }

  void waitThread()
  {
    //Thread waiting
    // Will do the std::bind sent at sendWork                                                    
  }
}
```

Has someone any idea?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is your problem related to the fact that you don't know the type? Or do you not understand how to pass data from one thread to another in general?

Comment: lookup "type erasure"

Comment: I don't know the type, that my problem, yes

Comment: Neither, to be we without code.

Comment: I've put some pseudo-code

Comment: If I understand the goal, it is not achieavable. You can not simply redirect a thread to start executing another function than the one it was created with. You need something like a task queue to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's not exactly that, I'm aware of the task queue, the problem is how to transit a generic bind type to another thread, I got a look at type erasure. I've the solution and will answer it in a few hours.

Comment: What do you mean by 'transfer'? How do you expect your other thread to receive it? This is times more important than 'bind' problem you are talking about, which is easily solvable with std::function.

Comment: "How do you expect your other thread to receive it?" Exactly my problem, yes I just have to send a std::function but I thought I could have the return but I'll have to work with callbacks instead, because the return type should be known at the compile time which is not the case because the other thread depends on run time actions taken by another thread.

Comment: Which means that I'd have to use std::function<void()>

Comment: Forget about type for a second. assume you have it. You have your MagicType. What's next? Show me the code for the thread which deals with MagicType object.

Comment: Type was my only problem, so it's pointless, but I highly thank you for trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: ofcourse it possible. I don't have the time to write a POC but you can wrap the callable with std::packaged_task, get the future out of it, wrap it again with std::function<void()> and send it this way to the background thread.

Comment: Could you please, prove it? I'm really interested, I think I know what you mean, I'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the commentaries, the only current way to pass a generic function to another thread is by using `std::function<void()>` which forbid any return type, but grants the ability to specify any parameters and number of parameters, in order to return results, you'll have to think about callbacks.